# iOS developer portal has multiple app ids when I only created 1

Tags: ios

I only remember creating 1 app id. Is there a default app id that apple automatically creates for my account? What is its purpose?

[image: 2 apps]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Apple doesn't create a default App ID when you create your account. Maybe someone else on your account created it?

Comment: Maybe I did it a while ago. I was able to delete